# @(Ionic/Angular) - ion-tabs Styling unable to hide element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

Let's introduce the issue:

- Here you have a link to StackBlitz example.
  [StackBlitz example Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-jwkyst?file=src/app/tabs/tabs.page.scss)
- What I am trying to achieve is to erase/hide the div-like element that is placed as a container for the ion-tab-buttons, but as far as I've seen there's no element nor shadow elements in inspector related to this one i told. (in the example from StackBlitz below the area is colored as green with opacity 0.4) but even with the opacity there's nothing shown behind.
- As I am writing this post I'm noticing that it might be something related to router-outlet sizing let me know what you think!!

There's no need to put the html code since it is a basic ionic tabs generated by the framework, so here it is the .scss:

```
ion-tab-bar {
  bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 92%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ion-tab-button {
  --color: var(--ion-color-medium);
  --color-selected: var(--ion-color-primary);
  --padding-end: 0;
  --padding-start: 0;
  &::before {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 2px;
  }

  &.tab-selected::before {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  }
}

//here you can see what it is the component i want to remove
//Even if you place it as transparent or opacity 0 there's no change, we are unable to see item list going up||down the tab buttons
ion-tabs {
  background: rgba(172, 255, 47, 0.425);
}
```

**Question: How can I make the ion-tab-buttons just floating without the "greenArea" shown in the StackBlitz Example?**

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't see the list under the tab bar is because content's height. In order to get the content full height of the page, you can go to `styles.css` and add

```
app-tabs > ion-tabs > .tabs-inner {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then instead of making your `ion-tab-bar` `position: relative`, you can make it `position: absolute`

Here the [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-9lmw1x?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.page.scss) where I fixed it, only need to position it a bit. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi @Zento this solution fixes the question below, but I'm a bit stuck with the scroll; how could I maximize the scroll height to be able to click on the item behind the tabs?! (use  Phone Screen Size)